# Detecting mouse clicks on video played with MCI commands

Tags: c#, mci

I have an application that plays video. I'm using MCI to play the video and attach it to a panel control. I'm catching mouse clicks on the main form and all the controls, but when I click on the video playing with MCI, it doesn't detect the mouse clicks.

How can you detect mouse clicks on a video played with MCI commands?

Comment: If you are attaching something to a panel control, what about handling clicks from that? UI controls should be able to handle clicks.

Comment: That won't work for some reason. thats the first thing i tried, passing a panels handle to the mci video, having that panel capture mouse clicks, and adding it to the main forms controls. the mouse clicks go through the entire form and click on whatever is behind the form. the main form never catches the mouse clicks

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by creating a borderless form which i pass in the handle of to the mci video. I set the form TransparencyKey to the backcolor. this way, the video still shows but the mouse clicks are passed through the to main form.

I'm setting the size and location of the form from the main form because for some reason it won't work by setting them from inside the form, which i'm still trying to understand why

```
    public VideoForm()
    {
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
        this.TopMost = true;
    }

    public void PlayVideo(int width, int height, ScreenControl control)
    {
        string mciCommand = string.Format("open \"{0}\" Type mpegvideo alias {1} parent {2} style child", control.Location(), control.Name, this.Handle.ToString());
        int error = WinApi.mciSendString(mciCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        mciCommand = string.Format("put {0} window at 0 0 {1} {2}", control.Name, width, height);
        error = WinApi.mciSendString(mciCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        mciCommand = string.Format("seek {0} to 0", control.Name);
        error = WinApi.mciSendString(mciCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        mciCommand = string.Format("play {0} repeat", control.Name);
        error = WinApi.mciSendString(mciCommand, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        this.Show();
    }
```